# How to do compute hash using md5 in java

Tags: java, encryption, hash, md5, hashcode

I have an issue of converting md5 hash code to byte code. Using C# ,service side from hash code they are generating some byte codes but i cant able to get same byte code. Please help me how to get same byte codes.

**C#:**

```
 MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5Hasher = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
 byte[] hashedBytes = null;
 UTF8Encoding encoder = new UTF8Encoding();
 hashedBytes = md5Hasher.ComputeHash(encoder.GetBytes(Loginentities.Password));
```

**encoder.GetBytes(Loginentities.Password)**

for this line am getting byte such as **[19, 15, 101, 15, 4, 104, 105, 14, 7, 1]**

hashedBytes am getting these bytes **[149,229,240 ,182 ,152 ,142 ,199, 3 ,232 ,50, 23, 47, 112, 206 ,125, 199]**

**hashcode:** 95e5f0b69asdda3e832172f70ce7dc7

Java:

```
String str1 ="ramprasad";
byte[] bytes1 = str1.getBytes();
System.out.println("uno shriram is "+Arrays.toString(bytes1));
```

for bytes1 am getting [117, 110, 111, 115, 104, 114, 105, 114, 97, 109]

```
     try {
                    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
                    byte[] array = md.digest(bytes);
                    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
                      sb.append(Integer.toHexString((array[i] & 0xFF) | 0x100).substring(1,3));
                   }
                    System.out.println( "0X"+sb.toString());
OUTPUT:0X95e5f0b21398asdas03e832172f70ce7dc7
                   String x= "0x"+sb.toString();
                    System.out.println(x.getBytes() );
OUTPUT:[B@1174b07
                    System.out.println("uno shriram is "+Arrays.toString(x.getBytes()));
OUTPUT:uno shriram is [48, 120, 57, 53, 101, 53, 102, 48, 98, 54, 57, 56, 56, 101, 99, 55, 48, 51, 101, 56, 51, 50, 49, 55, 50, 102, 55, 48, 99, 101, 55, 100, 99, 55]
                    try
                    {
                    byte[] bytesasd = x.getBytes("UTF-8");
                    MessageDigest m = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");

                    byte[] hashedbyte = m.digest(bytesasd);

                    System.out.println(hashedbyte);
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                } catch (java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                }
            try 
            {
                String doc2 = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
                System.out.println(""+doc2);
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

How to get exact hashed bytes in java. please help me how to get it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget to call `getBytes("UTF-8")` or your encoding may be off. Something like

```
String str1 = "unoshriram";
String outHash = "95e5f0b6988ec703e832172f70ce7dc7";
try {
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    byte[] array = md.digest(str1.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (byte b : array) {
        sb.append(String.format("%02X", b));
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
    System.out.println(sb.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(outHash));
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Output is

```
95E5F0B6988EC703E832172F70CE7DC7
true
```

Comment: I require this byte array from string elliot..[149,229,240 ,182 ,152 ,142 ,199, 3 ,232 ,50, 23, 47, 112, 206 ,125, 199]

Comment: You're never going to get that in Java. Since `byte` is signed it has a range -128 to 127. **Note** The hash codes do match.